# Remote debugging, GDB fails with SIGILL when hitting jal instruction

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, openwrt, gdbserver

i'm trying to remote debug a MIPS AR9331 som running OpenWRT but i'm having lots of trouble. 
Main problem is that when GDB step over a function loaded through shared library, it exits with SIGILL:

> No source available for "0x7fff6e0c"

Looking on the web it looks like a missing symbol problem, so i did make clean and recompiled the whole kernel with GLOBAL_DEBUG flag, and uClibc  with debug information.
I have copied the target /lib and /usr/lib folder in my linux host, added them to shared library path for GDB.

It looks like symbols are loaded:

```
info sharedlibrary
    From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
    0x77fdd0b0  0x77fe5060  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
    0x77fc6260  0x77fcaec0  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libuci.so
    0x77faec60  0x77fb3f00  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libubox.so
    0x77f7efc0  0x77f98900  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0
    0x77f482f0  0x77f68370  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libm.so.0
    0x77e9fe10  0x77f2aa10  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0
    0x77e756e0  0x77e83a50  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x77e5caf0  0x77e5fe60  Yes         /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libdl.so.
```

If i look for printf, for example, i get:

```
info symbol printf
printf in section .text of /home/paolo/trunk/openwrt/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0

info address printf
Symbol "printf" is at 0x77ee5d50 in a file compiled without debugging.

info function printf@plt
All functions matching regular expression "printf@plt":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00407510  printf@plt
0x00407580  snprintf@plt
0x00407670  vsnprintf@plt
0x00407730  fprintf@plt
0x00407960  sprintf@plt
```

The output for function specific commands is in contrast with info sharedlibrary output.

This is the disassebly view of a simple printf:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    signal(SIGINT, SIGHandler);
...
}

00401630:   save 96,ra
 48           printf("Hello world\n");
00401632:   lw a0,0x4016bc <main+140>
00401634:   jal 0x407531 <strerror@plt+1>
00401638:   nop 
 50           signal(SIGINT, SIGHandler);
0040163a:   lw a1,0x4016bc <main+140>
0040163c:   jal 0x4077e1 <signal@plt+1>
00401640:   li a0,2
```

First thing that looks weird is Line 4:

```
jal 0x407531 <strerror@plt+1>
```

shouldn't it be a call to printf@plt+1?

When GDB hits this line, it fails with SIGILL. If i print the registers before the instruction i can see:

```
info register
          zero       at       v0       v1       a0       a1       a2       a3
 R0   00000000 77ff3027 00401631 7fff6e0c 004065c0 7fff6e04 7fff6e0c 7fff6c80 
            t0       t1       t2       t3       t4       t5       t6       t7
 R8   00000000 0001e77c 00000000 00077ff3 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
            s0       s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6       s7
 R16  77fff000 004016e0 00000005 0000000f 00438a64 00000000 00438a64 00438a4c 
            t8       t9       k0       k1       gp       sp       s8       ra
 R24  00000000 00401631 00000000 00000000 77f493b0 7fff6c20 7fff6c80 77f27c00 
            sr       lo       hi      bad    cause       pc
      0000fc13 cccccccd 00000000 77f13f80 10800024 00401635 
           fsr      fir
      00000000 00000000
```

and after:

```
info registers
          zero       at       v0       v1       a0       a1       a2       a3
 R0   00000000 77ff3027 b2000500 7fff6e0c 004065c0 0040759c 7fff6e0c 7fff6c80 
            t0       t1       t2       t3       t4       t5       t6       t7
 R8   00000000 0001dea4 8253bb00 00077ff3 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
            s0       s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6       s7
 R16  77fff000 004016e0 00000005 0000000f 00438a64 00000000 00438a64 00438a4c 
            t8       t9       k0       k1       gp       sp       s8       ra
 R24  00000000 7fff6e0c 00000000 00000000 77f493b0 7fff6c20 7fff6c80 0040163b 
            sr       lo       hi      bad    cause       pc
      0000fc13 cccccccd 00000000 77f13f80 30800028 7fff6e0c 
           fsr      fir
      00000000 00000000
```

The PC is set to 0x7fff6e0c but it doesn't seem to be in the libc.so range. Where does this address come from?
I tried to look for strerror, and got

```
info function strerror
All functions matching regular expression "strerror":

File libc/string/__glibc_strerror_r.c:
char *__GI___glibc_strerror_r(int, char *, size_t);

File libc/string/__xpg_strerror_r.c:
int __GI___xpg_strerror_r(int, char *, size_t);

File libc/string/strerror.c:
char *__GI_strerror(int);

File libc/inet/herror.c:
const char *hstrerror(int);

File libc/inet/gai_strerror.c:
const char *gai_strerror(int);

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00407530  strerror@plt
```

I only see address of strerror@plt, but no address of strerror.

Could this be a reason why is not working? 
I'm thinking maybe gdb doesn't know how to resolve PLT address. 
How could i check/solve this?

If, instead of stepping over, i put a breakpoint after printf and run, GDB stops correctly and i get "Hello World" on console output.

My application is compiled with -g and -Oo options. I tried -g3, -ggdb3 with no luck.

I have no idea how to track the problem to the source, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried to compile on a older verision of the kernel (a bleeding edge) and it works. 
I've seen a difference in the disassebled code. On the working kernel i see JALX instructions instead of JAL, and on the printf it disasseble with printf@plt+1 instead of strerror@plt+1. 
Does anyone know how to address me to find a solution?